# How to merge 2 columns in Excel with a space

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a some basic columns in Excel like this:

```
Full Name    |    First Name    |    Last Name
             |    Billy         |    Bob
             |    Sue           |    Anne
             |    Super         |    Man
             |    Joe           |
```

I want to merge the first name and last name together into the Full Name column, separated by a space.

Is there a macro or something that could do that?

Also in the case of Joe who doesn't have a Last name listed, could it just put `Joe` without a space at the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in cell `A2`:

```
=TRIM(CONCATENATE($B2," ",$C2))
```

The trim should take care of that pesky space.

Comment: Also hint: put 4 spaces before the formula to get the markdown.

Comment: @Jerry You can edit another user's post if you see some formatting issue or whatever.

Comment: @Excellll I try to avoid edit other user's posts usually, unless strictly necessary ^^;

Comment: @Jerry Its absolutely ok to edit those answers. Don't be afraid of it. The site encourages users to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this formula, assuming that Full Name is in column A, First Name in column B and Last Name in column C, and you want the first name first.

```
=IF(OR(B2="",C2=""), B2&C2, B2&" "&C2)
```

Will work if either First Name or Last Name is missing.

EDIT: Overlooked a much simpler one to handle the spaces (credit to Wizard Prang)

```
=TRIM(B2&" "&C2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a formula, e.g.:

```
=A1&" "&B1
```

This is joining A1 to what ever is quoted (in this case a space) with B1.

To handle a missing first or last name, you could use an [IF statement](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-HP005209118.aspx).